# Sending Django debug page without exception

Tags: python, django

When my production Django site has an exception, Django automatically emails me the debug page, including a very detailed stacktrace. This is very useful for debugging.

But in some situations, I want Django to send me that useful stacktrace even if there isn't an exception. (For example if a user is doing a suspicious thing, or there's an exception I'm silencing but which I want to investigate.) I want to have a line of code that I could put anywhere in my Django logic that would cause Django to email me the stacktrace in the usual format.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Django has a logging system that is customizable and you can create your own logger configuration. In this particular case you would use a logger that is configured to use the mail_admins handler. I'll point you to the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/logging/) for all the details.

To include a stacktrace you would use logger.exception(), here is an example:

**views.py**

```
import logging

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

def trigger_500(request):
    try:
        10/0
    except Exception, exc:
        logging.exception(exc)
```

settings.py

```
'loggers': {
    'an_app.views': {
        'handlers': ['mail_admins', 'console'],
        'propagate': True,
     }
}
```

Comment: I already know about that, but the challenge is to include Django's debug page with a stacktrace in the email sent to admins.

Comment: Ram, I've updated my answer to include an example that provides a stacktrace. I've tested it in the console and it shows the traceback. I would assume it would have the same content in the email.

Comment: Thanks! This is helpful. Though I'd also want to be able to send a stacktrace even if there's no exception. Do you know how to do that?